# How to store multiline text in GAE datastore using Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I need to store a multiline text field in google app engine datastore using Java. I am currently using a "String" datatype. I know its possible to do this using python by defining StringProperty(multiline=True). How do I accomplish this using Java and String datatype on GAE?

thanks!

Comment: Did you tried standard `String` class?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to store it as a string. Prohibiting multiline strings by default is implemented in the SDK code in Python; I don't believe there's any such restriction in Java.

Note, though, that String fields are indexed; you probably don't want your multiline string indexed, and so you should use Text instead.